# Workflow Error - One or More Projects require additional setup

Tags: youtrack, youtrack-api

I've created a workflow in YouTrack with one rule.  However, on the Workflow screen, next to the name of my Workflow there is a box that says in red text, 'requires setup'.  When I hover over this it says, 'One or more projects require additional setup'.

Does anyone know what needs done to resolve this error?  I looked at the project and everything seems to be set up fine.

Any advice/help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, a field or field value that's required by the workflow is missing in the project. Expand the workflow row in the table, select a row corresponding to the rule, and in the form on the right you'll see what exactly is wrong and will have a chance to fix it pressing "Apply fixes".